# Using count(1) to calculate number of records of subqueries

Tags: oracle, count, subquery

I have below query to validate if the total records=5.

```
SELECT COUNT(1)
FROM (
  SELECT COUNT(*) AS total_records
  FROM tbl1
  WHERE version_key = '100047'
 UNION ALL
 SELECT COUNT(*) AS total_records
 FROM tbl2
 WHERE version_key = '100047'
) HAVING COUNT (*)=5;
```

The 2 subqueries has count = 2 and 3 respectively, however final count isn't returned as 5. Without `HAVING COUNT (*)=5`, the final count actually return as 2, which is the count of the last subquery.

Comment: What is it you really want to know? `COUNT(1)` is the same as `COUNT(*)` in the end. It counts the rows as well, but unnecessarily uses a constant expression for this, instead of telling the DBMS to count rows right away. Your subquery returns two rows which you count, although you know that result when looking at the query. You either want the `SUM(total_records)` or you don't want to aggregate the rows in the subquery, e.g. by replacing `COUNT(*) AS total_records` with `'count this row'` :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sub-query will return the counts of each table in each row. When using that as a reference table, the count(*) will only return the number of rows your sub-query generated, (always 2 in your case as you have two reference rows from the sub-query). You can use sum() function to add the results in each column. Can you try with below query and see if this is what you are expecting?

--- MYSQL Version -----

```
SELECT sum(total_records) as final_count
FROM (
  SELECT COUNT(*) AS total_records
  FROM tbl1
  WHERE version_key = '100047'
 UNION ALL
 SELECT COUNT(*) AS total_records
 FROM tbl2
 WHERE version_key = '100047'
) as final_table having final_count = 5;
```

----- EDIT 2 --------

Adding query for Oracle Database

```
SELECT sum(total_records) as final_count
FROM (
  SELECT COUNT(*) AS total_records
  FROM tbl1
  WHERE version_key = '100047'
 UNION ALL
 SELECT COUNT(*) AS total_records
 FROM tbl2
 WHERE version_key = '100047'
) having sum(total_records) = 5;
```

Hope this helps

Comment: The final count returns as 5 now. However, can I remain HAVING COUNT (*)=5 as I need it to be returned when the final count=5

Comment: Sorry that I missed that part, I edited the answer now with an updated query. Can you try the above?

Comment: I'm getting ORA-00933: SQL command not properly  near as final_table

Comment: Oh, I see you are using Oracle DB,
SELECT sum(total_records) as final_count
FROM (
  SELECT COUNT(*) AS total_records
  FROM tbl1
  WHERE version_key = '100047'
 UNION ALL
 SELECT COUNT(*) AS total_records
 FROM tbl2
 WHERE version_key = '100047'
) having sum(total_records) = 5;

Comment: Thanks, it works for my validation condition :)